# Problems with structure and linking pages

Tags: php, include

I'm new to php. I'm developing a website with this sort of structure

```
root
Index.php
Dir1
  (Files)
 - Page.php
Dir2
  (Files)
Includes
 - Header.php
 - Footer.php
 - Newfile.php
 - Style.css
.htaccess
```

Now, my problem is how to link page.php and index.php dinamically to all includes files.
I have been using include() but I have problems because page.php and index.php aren't in the same directory. In addition if header includes newfile.php it can be shown in index.php but not in page.php.

Comment: I understand you are new to PHP; however, it is worth mentioning that there are frameworks like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) that help resolve issues like this and help keep your code structured well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** if you are working on localhost, i assume you can access and change your `php.ini` - file. you can set your `include_path` there.

see http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path :

Example #1 Unix include_path

```
include_path=".:/php/includes"
```

Example #2 Windows include_path

```
include_path=".;c:\php\includes"
```

without having too much privileges on your server and without using other tools, it's a bit complicated. but here is a solution which might still save quite some time.
in your root directory, create a file for your include-paths:

```
<?php 
    //content of path.php

    $root = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];

    $path = array();

    $path[]= $root;
    $path[]= $root.'/Dir1';
    $path[]= $root.'/Dir2';
    $path[]= $root.'/Includes';

    //you can add more paths here, for example:
    $path[]= $root.'/NewDir';

    foreach($path AS $key => $value)
    {
        set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $value);
    }
?>
```

then, in every other file you have to add one line before your includes:

```
<?php
    //in every other php file
    require_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/path.php";
?>
```

but that's the only line you have to add to be able to include all files which are part of the path you just defined.
so if you want to include `Newfile.php` from within `Page.php`:

```
<?php
    //Page.php
    require_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/path.php";

    include "Newfile.php";
?>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer. Now I will try to implement it in my website.

Comment: Hi, I get an error including path.php with $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"], probably because I am in localhost? failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: see my updated answer. there's also another way to change your `include_path` via `.htaccess` file - don't know if you have tried that.

Comment: I managed to make it work (without changing php.ini), the only problem is with style.css which is included in the header.php, I don't know which path to use for that, because it's still different form index.php to page.php and has to be included in both

Comment: you should avoid to use `PHP` includes for anything else than `PHP` files! `css` files should be always included using `html`: `<LINK href="mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

Comment: yes, I know, I have used that syntax but the problem is that href="style.css" changes from page.php (href="../includes/style.css") to index.php (href="includes/style.css")

Comment: use the absolute path to your css file on all pages: `"/includes/style.css"`. starting with `/` returns to the root directory and starts there: http://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot, now I think I have everything clear ;) it's working.

Comment: you are welcome! please consider marking my answer as accepted if it did help you solving your problem.